# Use unique title tags for both Twitter share and Facebook share... og:title overwriting twitter:title

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have two social share meta tags I am using `og:title` for Facebook and `twitter:title` for Twitter. I need each to be different. Twitter always uses the open graph title and I need to find a way to give each share titles different content. Currently my code is as follows.

```
<meta content="my unique title for facebook" property="og:title" />
<meta content="a description tag here for facebook" property="og:description" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="my unique title for twitter content" />
```

The share feature is using "Add This" https://www.addthis.com/academy/setting-the-url-title-to-share/ the software is a template for multiple sites so it isn't easy to edit the HTML I want to find a solution using only meta tags.

I am using

```
<meta name="twitter:title" content="my content" />
```

and share this Twitter share is still using OG tag.

The Add This code looks like

```
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var addthis_config = {
          services_compact: 'email, facebook, twitter, digg, reddit, linkedin, myspace, plaxo, blogger, livejournal, more',
          services_exclude: 'print'
      };
      var addthis_share = {
           url_transforms : {
                shorten: {
                     twitter: 'bitly'
                }
           }, 
           shorteners : {
                bitly : {} 
           }
      };

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-56e1e3b04418084b"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

HTML

```
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="menuLink addthis_button"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Share</span></a>
```

Comment: Try if maybe changing the order helps ...? If not, then you might need to resort to reading the requesting User-Agent server-side, and only output one or the other set of OG meta.

Comment: Thanks I did try this, but twitter:title was still not respected

Comment: It should be `<meta name="twitter:title" content="blah">` instead of property. See if that helps, as the twitter docs say what you want to do is totally possible

Comment: @JonChurch You should add this as answer. According to the test I made on https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator now it works as expected. And OP already edited the question so the bounty should be yours.

Comment: Right I tried it. It still taking the OG tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Twitter's scraper will always take twitter meta tags over open graph**

According to their docs:

> When the Twitter card processor looks for tags on a page, it first
>   checks for the Twitter-specific property, and if not present, falls
>   back to the supported Open Graph property. This allows for both to be
>   defined on the page independentl

OP edited their question, they originally were using property tags instead of name tags

It should be

`<meta name="twitter:title" content="blah">`

instead of

`<meta property="twitter:title" content="blah">`

With this change, it works.

Comment: No with this change the result is still the same.

Comment: If that's the case then its likely an issue with the share plugin you are using, and not your meta tags. Please share the code for the share box you are using.

Comment: I posted the code for the share plugin, the tags all seem to be correct now, but still using OG.

Comment: I reached out to add this support and they had this to say: "... when a user uses our tools to share a web page, we scrape that URL for their OG tags or Twitter cards and send that to the social service to process.   With that said, it odd that this is not working for the user you are helping. It's best if they can share the URL of the website that this issue is occurring so we can investigate further. Can you ask them to contact us directly so we can get this sorted out?"

Comment: Thanks you deserve the bounty for this man! I'll keep on it myself.

Comment: Cool, award the bounty whenever you see fit =]